# Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch with KinectJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, kinect

I'm trying to use *KinectJS*, but when I send the remote address to the demo using the modal, I got the following error:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch,=
INVALID SOCKET
```

The application cannot establish the connection via WebSocket, it seems to be related to the Kinect's server `KinectSocketServer` provided by the library, in particular, the base64 request header may be wrong...

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Did you ever find a solution or get in touch with the library author?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem and the author of the library hasn't responded to the mail I sent him one month ago...

Comment: Oh well, that's unfortunate. However, if you're still interested in working with the Kinect using JavaScript I found an alternative library that works great: http://zigfu.com/en/zdk/overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two WebSocket handshake protocols out there depending on the WebSocket draft version being followed. KinectJS is likely using an older implementation.

Please see the [latest official WebSocket draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17) for details on the correct handshake protocol to use.

Comment: Thanks, and can I change the protocol directly in the library kinect.js? (I can't modify the socket server with which it communicates because it's a swf format)

Comment: The server script is in SWF format? That's weird. I would think that any SWF file that's included in the library would purely be for the Flash fallback in the event that both WebSocket and Ajax long polling are not possible. I'd search through all the server-side scripts for the part where the headers sent from the client are parsed to create the response, and edit that as per the WebSocket draft linked above.

Comment: In fact, you must install the flash program on the client machine to let the kinect communicate with the library kinect.js (which is hosted on the website server) via websocket. So it's not an alternative to the websocket because both swf and js files use websockets...
And I do not know which of these two files I have to implement the new websocket handshake. I just can't modify the swf, so if the swf has the bad protocol, I have to tell it to the library creator, pkalogiros.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to have to plead ignorance on this one. Sorry. What really doesn't bode well for this discussion is that when I did a Google search for "KinectJS WebSocket", the first hit was a bunch of useless YouTube video comments, and the second was this discussion. If you absolutely cannot find the handshake code in the JS file(s), I'd get a SWF decompiler program and use that to view the SWF file code, in which you can hopefully find what you're looking for. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: Okay, so I'll try to do this and if I can't fix the protocol, I think I'll tell the support that the library is currently broken... Thanks for your help!